# QGIS custom Python expressions not loading on startup

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-custom-function

My custom Python expressions are not loading at startup and I dont know why. Its a real pain because I have virtual layers depending on those expressions, so after I load them I have to manually refresh those virtual layers' queries... I have not found an option in QGIS options to fix this.

Comment: Custom Python expressions a stored within the user profile folder: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\English\python\expressions. If you changed the Userprofile they will not be loaded automatically in the new or other user profile...

Comment: In my case,in Profiles folder I only have /default/python/expressions/... I have changed my QGIS languaje to english a long time ago, so I tryed changing back the language, but they didn't load. Manually creating that set of folders didn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, following the thread from @eurojam (thanks eurojam!!) I found in expressions folder two python files, the one with my custom expressions and another called "__ init __"... So I moved all my expressions to __ init __, launched QGIS and voilá! Problem solved